# Generating PDF dynamically through fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF dynamically using fpdf, but I am finding it very difficult. Only half of the result I could get. I want to generate my PDF like this:

[image: Intended result]

And now I get a result like this:

[image: Actual result]

Here is the code for PDF:

```
<?php


require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');
error_reporting(-1);


$id = $_GET['order_id'];
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','dbnme'); // use your credentials

class INVPDF extends FPDF
{
    var $id;
    var $today;
    var $widths;
    var $heads;
    var $aligns;
    var $formats;
    var $db;
    var $invTotal = 0;
    var $advancePaid = 0; 



        //constructor
        function INVPDF($invno, $db)
        {
            parent::fpdf();
            $this->id = $invno;
            $this->db = $db;
            $this->today = date('jS M Y');
            $this->heads = array('Item', 'UOM', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Disc %', 'Tax', 'Frt', 'Total' );
            $this->widths = array (45, 15, 35, 15, 15, 20, 25, 30);
            $this->aligns = array ('L','C','L','C','C','R','C', 'C');
            $this->formats = array (0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0);
        }

        //Page header
        function Header()
        {        
                //Arial bold 15
                //Title
                include("../connect.php");




                $ss1 = "select orders.sales_order_id, orders.company_id, lead_address.address, lead_address.address_category, lead_address.country, lead_address.state, lead_address.company_id, lead_address.city,lead_address.pin from orders INNER JOIN lead_address ON orders.company_id=lead_address.company_id where lead_address.address_category='Billing' AND orders.sales_order_id='".$_GET['order_id']."'";
                $mq1 = mysql_query($ss1) or die(mysql_error());
                $rr1 = mysql_fetch_array($mq1);

                $billing = $rr1['address'];
                list($line1, $line2, $line3) = explode(',',$billing);
                $country = $rr1['country'];
                $state = $rr1['state'];
                $city = $rr1['city'];
                $pin = $rr1['pin'];
                //list($line1, $line2, $country, $state, $city, $pin) = explode(',',$address);
                $ss2 = "select orders.sales_order_id, orders.company_id, lead_address.address, lead_address.address_category, lead_address.country, lead_address.state, lead_address.company_id, lead_address.city,lead_address.pin from orders INNER JOIN lead_address ON orders.company_id=lead_address.company_id where lead_address.address_category='Shipping' AND orders.sales_order_id='".$_GET['order_id']."'";

                $mq2 = mysql_query($ss2) or die(mysql_error());
                $rr2 = mysql_fetch_array($mq2);

                $shipping = $rr2['address'];

                $country1 = $rr2['country'];
                $state1 = $rr2['state'];
                $city1 = $rr2['city'];
                $pin1 = $rr2['pin'];


                //$email = $rr1['email'];
//              $phone = $rr1['phone'];
//              $mobile = $rr1['mobile'];
//                $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);

                $this->setXY(10,20);
               // $this->Cell(0,10,'INVOICE '.$this->id,0,2,'L');
                $this->Image('logo.png',20,6,15);
                $this->setXY(12,20);
                //
                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
                $this->Cell(0,10,'Company Name. ',0,2,'L');
                $this->Cell(0,0,'Address1, address2',0,2,'L');
                $this->Cell(0,8,'city, stte',0,2,'L');

                $this->Cell(0,2,'sales@company.com',0,2,'L');
                //$this->Image('images/logo.png',10,6,60);

                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
                $this->setXY(12,50);
                $this->Cell(0,-2,'Shipping Address',$this->id,0,2,0,'L');
                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);

                $this->setXY(12,52);
                $this ->MultiCell(57,22,'', 'LRTB', 'L', 1);
                //$this->Cell(0,8,$name,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');
                $this->setXY(12,55);
                $this->Cell(0,-1,$shipping,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');



                $this->setXY(12,53);
                $this->Cell(0,10,$country." , ".$state,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                $this->setXY(12,52);
                $this->Cell(0,20,$city." , ".$pin,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
                $this->setXY(140,52);
                $this ->MultiCell(57,22,'', 'LRTB', 'L', 1);

                $this->setXY(140,34);
                $this->Cell(0,30,'Billing Address',$this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
                $this->setXY(140,35);
                $this->Cell(0,40,$line1." , ".$line2, $this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                $this->setXY(140,35);
                $this->Cell(0,49,$line3, $this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                $this->setXY(140,33);
                $this->Cell(0,62,$city1." , ".$pin1,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                $this->setXY(140,33);
               $this->Cell(0,70,$country1." , ".$state1,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');



                //$this->setXY(12,65);
//              $this->Cell(0,60,$phone,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');

                //$this->setXY(12,65);
                //$this->Cell(0,70,$mobile,$this->id,0,2,0,'L');
                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
                $this->setXY(10,5);
                $this->Cell(0,10,'QUOTATION:  '.$this->id,0,2,'R');



                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
                $until = date ('jS F Y', strtotime($this->today));
                $this->Cell(0,0,'Date: '.$until,0,2,'R');

                $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
               $this->Cell(0,10,'Due Date: Due on receipt',0,2,'R');





                //Line break
                $this->Ln(60);
                for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++)
                {
                    $this->Cell ($this->widths[$i], 8, $this->heads[$i], 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                }
                $this->Ln(8);
        }

        //Page footer
       function Footer()
        {

            # $this->SetY(-50);          // Uncomment to position at 5 cm from bottom
            //Arial italic 8
            $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',8);
            $w = array_sum(array_slice($this->widths,0,3));
            $this->Cell($w,12,'',1);
            $this->Cell($this->widths[3],12,'',1,0,'C');

            $this->setLeftMargin(45 + array_sum(array_slice($this->widths,0,4)));

            $this->Cell($this->widths[5],4,'Sub Total',1);
            $this->Cell($this->widths[6],4,number_format($this->invTotal,2),1,0,'R');
            $this->Cell($this->widths[7],4,'USD',1,1,'C');

            $this->Cell($this->widths[5],4,'Tax',1);
            $this->Cell($this->widths[6],4,number_format($this->advancePaid,2),1,0,'R');
            $this->Cell($this->widths[7],4,'USD',1,1,'C');

             $this->Cell($this->widths[5],4,'Freight',1);
            $this->Cell($this->widths[6],4,number_format($this->freight,2),1,0,'R');
            $this->Cell($this->widths[7],4,'USD',1,1,'C');

            $this->setLeftMargin(10);

            $this->Cell($this->widths[5],4,'Total',1);
            $this->Cell($this->widths[6],4,number_format($this->invTotal+$this->advancePaid,2),1,0,'R');
            $this->Cell($this->widths[7],4,'USD',1,1,'C');



            $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',6);
            $this->Cell($w,10,'',0,0,'L');
            $this->Cell(30,4,'Private Limited Company - TIN: 345sddd - PAN: sf43534',0,0,'C');
            //$this->Cell($w,10,'');
            $this->Cell(-30,12,'SRVC TAX: gddddddddddd - CIN: sdgdgdgdfgfdgfg',0,0,'C');
            $this->Cell(30,20,'This document has been electronically generated and requires no physical signature or stamp.',0,0,'C');



        }

        function makeInvoice()
          {


            $sql =  "select before_order_line_items.item, before_order_line_items.description, before_order_line_items.uom, before_order_line_items.selling_price, before_order_line_items.quantity, before_order_line_items.discount, before_order_line_items.tax, before_order_line_items.freight, before_order_line_items.tax_amount, before_order_line_items.total, items.name as iname, taxes.tax_id, taxes.name as tname, taxes.rate from before_order_line_items inner join items on before_order_line_items.item=items.item_id inner join taxes on before_order_line_items.tax=taxes.tax_id where before_order_line_items.sales_order_id = '".$_GET['order_id']."' ";

            //echo $sql;    

            $res = $this->db->query($sql) or die($this->db->error);
            $this->SetFont('OpenSans','',8);
            if ($res->num_rows > 0)
            {

                while ($r = $res->fetch_row())
                {

                    $this->invTotal += $r[10];


                    foreach ($r as $c => $value) {
                        //echo $value;
                       if ($this->formats[$c]) {
                           $value = number_format($value);
                          // echo $value;

                        }
                        $this->Cell($this->widths[$c],10,$value,'LR',0, $this->aligns[$c]);


                    }
                    $this->Ln();
                    //$amount = number_format($amount+$value);

                }
            }            
        }

} # invpdf class

$invno = $_GET['order_id'];
//Instantiation of inherited class
$pdf = new INVPDF($invno, $db);

$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->setLeftMargin(10);
$pdf->setRightMargin(10);
$pdf->AddFont('OpenSans','','Opensans-Regular.php');
$pdf->SetFont('OpenSans','',7);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(102);
$pdf->SetFillColor(220);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->makeInvoice();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Can somebody please help me how to do it? or is there any example code for something similar to this?

Comment: (Please use the Stack Exchange image server in the future, so links are less likely to break in the long term. I've edited them in for you now).

Comment: Thank you, but i do not have access sufficient reputation to post image.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your actual pdf and expected pdf.. you are missing the no. column in table header.
This line-

```
$this->heads = array('Item', 'UOM', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Disc %', 'Tax', 'Frt', 'Total' );
```

should be-

```
$this->heads = array('No.', 'Item', 'UOM', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Disc %', 'Tax', 'Frt', 'Total' );
```